# Problems binding Data on DataTemplate from the template

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, binding

FindAncestor,I'm trying to bind on the element local:ItemPresenter the property EndDate. EndDate is defined in local:Presenter. But it doesn't binding the Value of EndDate on the Element.

```cs
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Presenter}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Presenter}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                                <ContentControl.Resources>
                                    <!-- more Typed DataTemplates -->
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type item:ItemSubProjects}">
                                        <local:ItemPresenter
                                            EndDate="{Binding EndDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:Presenter}}">
                                        </local:ItemPresenter>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ContentControl.Resources>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You've missed out the mode in the relativesource binding `{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:Presenter}`

Comment: It didn't help to solve the problem.

Comment: And EndDate is a DependencyProperty?

Comment: Yes, EndDate is a DependencyProperty in `local:Presenter` and `local:ItemPresenter`. I didn't how binding it works in Custom Control, but same rebuild in a window with datacontext work.

Comment: Have you removed the `{x:Type}` bit yet?

Comment: I removed `{x: Type}`, but forget to update it above!

Comment: Next step would be to try moving the assignment of EndDate to a style, like in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Explicit pointing the `DataContext` in bindings may help you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `x:Type` binding here you can just pass the type.  Additionally you haven't specified the mode to the relative source binding.

Additionally you may want to move the ItemPresenter property settings to a style too.

Try this instead.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ItemPresenter">
  <Setter Property="EndDate" Value="{Binding EndDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:Presenter}" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Presenter}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Presenter}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                                <ContentControl.Resources>
                                    <!-- more Typed DataTemplates -->
                                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type item:ItemSubProjects}">
                                        <local:ItemPresenter />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ContentControl.Resources>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: This didn't work for my example than i realized this in code not yaml and it worked.